# Linux is detecting only 2 GB of RAM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arch-linux, antergos

I've recently installed antergos, Arch Linux distro. I have 6 GB of RAM and only 2 GB is being detected. I installed the 64-bit version. On the BIOS, there is 6 GB of memory. I have also used Ubuntu and it detects 2 GB as well. Other Linux distros do the same. I also reseated my RAM slots with no luck.

I've tried the following:

> **$ free -m**
>
> ```
>               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
> Mem:           1964        1411          80          37         472         596
> Swap:          3814           0        3814
> ```
>
> **lshw -c memory**
>
> ```
>   *-cache:0
>        description: L1 cache
>        physical id: 5
>        slot: L1-Cache
>        size: 384KiB
>        capacity: 384KiB
>        clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
>        capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
>        configuration: level=1
>   *-cache:1
>        description: L2 cache
>        physical id: 6
>        slot: L2-Cache
>        size: 8MiB
>        capacity: 8MiB
>        clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
>        capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
>        configuration: level=2
>   *-cache:2
>        description: L3 cache
>        physical id: 7
>        slot: L3-Cache
>        size: 8MiB
>        capacity: 8MiB
>        clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
>        capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
>        configuration: level=3
>   *-memory
>        description: System Memory
>        physical id: 2c
>        slot: System board or motherboard
>        size: 6GiB
>      *-bank:0
>           description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
>           product: Dimm0_PartNum
>           vendor: Dimm0_Manufacturer
>           physical id: 0
>           serial: Dimm0_SerNum
>           slot: Node0_Dimm0
>      *-bank:1
>           description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
>           product: 1333EL Series
>           vendor: Undefined
>           physical id: 1
>           serial: 00000000
>           slot: Node0_Dimm1
>           size: 2GiB
>           width: 64 bits
>           clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
>      *-bank:2
>           description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
>           product: CMZ8GX3M2A160
>           vendor: Corsair
>           physical id: 2
>           serial: 00000000
>           slot: Node0_Dimm2
>           size: 4GiB
>           width: 64 bits
>           clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
>      *-bank:3
>           description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
>           product: Dimm3_PartNum
>           vendor: Dimm3_Manufacturer
>           physical id: 3
>           serial: Dimm3_SerNum
>           slot: Node0_Dimm3
> ```
>
> **# lshw -short | grep 'System Memory'**
>
> ```
> /0/2c                         memory      6GiB System Memory
> ```
>
> **$ uname -a**
>
> ```
> Linux <hostname> 4.12.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 28 18:54:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```
>
> **dmesg**

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.12.4-1-ARCH (builduser@nspawn-9860) (gcc version 7.1.1 20170630 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 28 18:54:18 UTC 2017
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=d597d2b0-dbcd-4e9b-8326-df9ce1547828 rw quiet resume=UUID=30a347fd-841f-4417-9dfe-c5b5ac793d4c
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007d478fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007d479000-0x000000007da36fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007da37000-0x000000007de34fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007de35000-0x000000007e101fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e102000-0x000000007e154fff] type 20
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e155000-0x000000007e155fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e156000-0x000000007e35bfff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007e35c000-0x000000007e7fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec20000-0x00000000fec20fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed61000-0x00000000fed70fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed8ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fef00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
```

Comment: The map covers only 32 bit address space. What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: uname -a
Linux cesard11 4.12.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 28 18:54:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This is not a linux problem. Often there are hw limitations where the memories have to match. For maximum chances of success, 2 DIMs of 4 GB. Beware of the limitations of the motherboard/device too.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro If that was the problem, then the BIOS should report 2GB. Cesar, what do you see in the BIOS **exactly**? Does it say that 6GB of memory is available, or are you adding up a report that lists the connected DIMMs? What motherboard model is it?

Comment: Do try to put the modules in slots 0 and 1 rather than 1 and 2.

Comment: @Gilles I have seen RAM sizes and disk sizes in firmware/BIOS in the past that I was not able to use due to limitations of the architecture. We do not have enough data, for instance, the question does not mention either make or model.